# How to link folder in page viewer web part

Tags: 2013, web-part, page-viewer-web-part

I need to display folder content in a page using page viewer web part. But it is throwing below error while pasting the link of the folder. Please help me to locate the folder in the shared documents.

> The path to the folder is not valid for the Link property. Check the
>   spelling and syntax, and then type a valid path.

I am linking with the url some thing like below:

> https://learning.company.com/sites/dashboard/SiteAssets/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fdashboard%2FSiteAssets%2Fhome&PageView=Shared&FolderCTID=0x0120009F43D36E7B4C004CA6AA6D840CDA2FB8&View=%7B004E31E4%2D0DBF%2D4051%2DA210%2DDF9DB3736DF8%7D

My folder is under siteAssets/home

Comment: Home is your folder name?

Answer (score 1):

Considering `Home` is your folder name which you need to set in page viewer webpart try below url:

```
https://learning.company.com/sites/dashboard/SiteAssets/Home
```

This should work well with your Page Viewer Webpart.

If you have another folder inside home, say folder named `Test` url should look like below

```
https://learning.company.com/sites/dashboard/SiteAssets/Home/Test
```

Comment: you can mark it as answer if works for you. would be helpful for others too